# Hadoop distcp to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying the below command to transfer files form hdfs to aws s3 bucket.

Below is the code

```
  hadoop distcp \
  -Dfs.s3a.access.key=AKIXXXXXXXX4C7GA \
  -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=N12XXXXXXXXary24OXPt \
  -Dfs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
  hdfs://qa/user/dev_test/KL/TEST.csv s3a://Cust- 
   import/dcp/ua.10456754/119XXXX079
```

I am getting the below timeout error.

18/11/14 00:47:45 INFO http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to Cust-import.s3.amazonaws.com:443 timed out
com.cloudera.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to optimizely-import.s3.amazonaws.com:443 timed out
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:416)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:128)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at com.cloudera.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:728)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
    at com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:441)